# Working with multiarch shared libraries on Debian

Tags: boost, linker, debian

I try to link my program with `libboost_thread-mt` on a Debian machine. It worked well on Debian 7 (wheezy) but it fails on Debian 8 (Jessie). On Wheezy the library version was 1.49, and on Jessie it is 1.55. The package is now using `multi-arch` scheme, which means that it used to be under `/usr/lib` and now it is under `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. What do I need to do in order to link it properly without using `-L`?

Comment: And suddenly, all those linux guys claiming how programming under linux is easy are silent... I'm stuck at the same problem, have you come to any solution using multi-arch?

Comment: @TomášZato What is your machine arch? If it is amd64, you can force installation of the 64 bit version (`libboost_thread-mt:amd64`). Otherwise, it is possible that you might need to install the pacakges `libc6-i386` and also `libc6-i386-dev` which are required for using i386 packages on amd64 machines.

Comment: I have installed `libc6-i386` and the `libc6-i386-dev` cannot be located by `apt-get`.

Comment: sorry, it was `libc6-dev-i386`

Comment: In the meantime I figured out that I can use just `libboost_thread` which is available in both x86x64 and i386. As of paths, I simply have a IF statement in my makefile that alters between `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`